# How to write unit test with jest to check if-else block that returns the same value

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the below written function for which I need to write the unit test with jest:

```
export const functionToTest=(condition:boolean)=>{
  if(condition){
    return getDataFromCache()
  }
  else{
    return getDataFromApi()
  }
}
```

I have been asked to write the unit test to make sure that the respective functions are called based on the condition. I could have easily checked for the return value had they been different, but since the return values from the child functions are same it has become difficult to write the unit test case as wanted. Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing two tests, one for each block in the if/else statement:

```js
it("should get data from cache", async () => {
  const condition = true;
  const result = await functionToTest(condition);
  // expect stuff
})

it("should get data from api", async () => {
  const condition = false;
  const result = await functionToTest(condition);
  // expect stuff
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I have already written that, but seems like another unit test needs to be written to verify which function was called when.

Comment: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2017fa/thoughtful.html